# A simple probability problem, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability

This is a problem from a school(!) textbook:

*Probability of a poor harvest is 50%. However 30% of the time a disease increases this probability to 80%. Given that there is a poor harvest, what is the probability of a disease?*

My solution: 
Probability of a poor harvest when disease takes place: 0.3 * 0.8 = 0.24.
Probability of a poor harvest in the absence of disease:  0.7 * 0.5 = 0.35. 
Total probability of a poor harvest: 0.24 + 0.35 = 0.59
Probability of disease given poor harvest is 0.24/0.59, which is about 41%.

However the textbook answer is 48%. What is wrong?

Comment: The total probability of a poor harvest is 0.5, that means that the probability of a poor harvest in absence of disease is less than 0.5, so that the sum of the two is 0.5

Comment: Yes it looks like they divided 0.24 by 0.5, but I can't see the reason why total probability can't exceed 50%, given that the disease makes it 80%.

Comment: @cyanide because disease in not highly likely, it is just $30\%$  hence it don't exceed

Comment: The 50% does not refer to the probability of 'poor harvest with no disease', but rather 'poor harvest'. The word 'increases' trips you up, here, since it suggests that the 50% refers to the situation without a disease. Backward-logic when seeing the answer explains what was actually meant in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just misunderstood the condition, making it even  harder. Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that

PH: event corresponding to poor harvest

D : event corresponding to Disease

given

$$p(PH)= 0.5 , p(PH|D) = 0.8, p(D) = 0.3 $$

we need to find

$$p(D|PH) = \frac{p(PH|D)p(D)}{p(PH)} = \frac{0.8.0.3}{0.5 } = 0.48$$

Comment: Well, I just  misunderstood the condition. 0.5 is TOTAL probability of poor harvest, not probability of a poor harvest given the absense of  disease!

Comment: @cyanide also it is better to properly write in form of events and all . So that you can clearly state your assumptions :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is just a poorly worded problem. I can see two interpretations:
(i) The probability of a poor harvest is 50% without the disease. The disease happens with probability 30%, and every time it happens the probability of a poor harvest becomes 80%.
(ii) The probability of a poor harvest is 50% unconditionally. The disease happens with probability 30%, and when it does happen, the probability of a poor harvest is 80%.
Your solution is consistent with (i), and the textbook answer is consistent with (ii). I agree with your interpretation though.